# Android service always null

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm trying to start a service, but always getting NPE. What could I be doing wrong?
Even the `onServiceConnected()` method does not get called, why ever?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
       bindService(mServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
       //other stuff
    }
```

usage:

```
private okButton(View v) {
    startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

result: NullPointerException!

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
          @Override
          public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
               Log.v("service", "gets never executed!");
               mDownloadService = ((LocalBinder<MyService>) service).getService();
            }

        @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            }
        };
}

public class LocalBinder<S> extends Binder {
    private String TAG = "LocalBinder";
    private  WeakReference<S> mService;


    public LocalBinder(S service){
        mService = new WeakReference<S>(service);
    }


    public S getService() {
        return mService.get();
    }
}
```

Of course I also have the service in manifest:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".service.MyService" />
```

Logcat:

```
06-06 23:48:20.411: W/dalvikvm(592): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at MyActivity.okButton(MyActivity.java:217)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1939)
06-06 23:48:20.461: E/AndroidRuntime(592):  ... 11 more
```

The intent seems to be ok:

```
Log.v("service", String.valueOf(mServiceIntent == null)); //false
```

Comment: You don't give us context for the call to `startService(mServiceIntent);` but if this is the line number given for the `NullPointerException`, then it seems `mServiceIntent` is not initialized before you call it.  Where are you calling it from?

Comment: Calling from a custom method after button press, eg: `okButton()` inside my main activity. Where also all code above is located. So nothing special about this that's why I left it out prior.

Comment: Post the logcat showing the NPE stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace clearly shows the `NullPointerException` happening in `okButton()`, and according to the code you posted, the only line in that function is

```
    startService(mServiceIntent);
```

So clearly `mServiceIntent` is null at this point, despite being set in `onCreate()`.

Do you have any other lines where you set `mServiceIntent`?

Or do you have a constructor in which you call `okButton()`?  A constructor is the only thing I can think of that would run before `onCreate()`.  That would also explain why `onServiceConnected()` is never run despite the call to `bindService()` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: No there is no other code using or initing the intent. I can even use `mServiceIntent.putExtra(..)` before the `startService(mServiceIntent)`. The NPE occures on startService, but putExtra does not complain. So I expect the intent not to be null?

Comment: I also just checked if the intent is == null, and got false in the output. So intent seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not proper Java syntax, as the method definition has no return type :

```
private okButton(View v) {
    startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

You need something like:

```
private void okButton(View v) {
    startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

It looks to me from the stack trace that the `okButton()` method is being called during the creation of the MyActivity instance before the onCreate() method is called and of course at that time mService will be null.

Post more code or correct the code you've posted so that it actually matches what you are using.